# What's the meaning of pool_connections in requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

When initializing a requests' `Session`, two [`HTTPAdapter`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter) will be created and [mount to `http` and `https`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L340-L341).

This is how `HTTPAdapter` is defined:

```
class requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=10, pool_maxsize=10,
                                    max_retries=0, pool_block=False)
```

While I understand the meaning of `pool_maxsize`(which is the number of session a pool can save), I don't understand what `pool_connections` means or what it does. Doc says:

```
Parameters: 
pool_connections – The number of urllib3 connection pools to cache.
```

But what does it mean "to cache"? And what's the point using multiple connection pools?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Requests uses [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to manage its connections and other features.

Re-using connections is an important factor in keeping recurring HTTP requests performant. [The urllib3 README explains](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3#why-do-i-want-to-reuse-connections):

> **Why do I want to reuse connections?**
>
> Performance. When you normally do a urllib call, a separate socket connection is created with each request. By reusing existing sockets (supported since HTTP 1.1), the requests will take up less resources on the server's end, and also provide a faster response time at the client's end. [...]

To answer your question, "pool_maxsize" is the number of connections to keep around per host (this is useful for multi-threaded applications), whereas "pool_connections" is the number of host-pools to keep around. For example, if you're connecting to 100 different hosts, and `pool_connections=10`, then only the latest 10 hosts' connections will be re-used.

Comment: Are www.xxx.com and www.xxx.com/aaa same host?

Comment: @laike9m yes, it's the same host

Answer (score 80):

I wrote an [article](https://laike9m.com/blog/requests-secret-pool_connections-and-pool_maxsize,89/) about this. pasted it here:

## Requests' secret: pool_connections and pool_maxsize

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is one of the, if not the most well-known Python third-party library for Python programmers. With its simple API and high performance, people tend to use requests instead of urllib2 provided by standard library for HTTP requests. However, people who use requests every day may not know the internals, and today I want to introduce two of them: `pool_connections` and `pool_maxsize`.

Let's start with `Session`:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://www.google.com')
```

It's pretty simple. You probably know requests' `Session` can persists cookie. Cool. But do you know `Session` has a [`mount`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.mount) method?

> `mount(prefix, adapter)`
>   Registers a connection adapter to a prefix.
>   Adapters are sorted in descending order by key length.

No? Well, in fact you've already used this method when you [initialize a `Session` object](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L340-L341):

```
class Session(SessionRedirectMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        # Default connection adapters.
        self.adapters = OrderedDict()
        self.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter())
        self.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter())
```

Now comes the interesting part. If you've read Ian Cordasco's article [Retries in Requests](http://www.coglib.com/~icordasc/blog/2014/12/retries-in-requests.html), you should know that `HTTPAdapter` can be used to provide retry functionality. But what is an `HTTPAdapter` really? Quote from [doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):

> `class requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=10, pool_maxsize=10, max_retries=0, pool_block=False)`
>
> The built-in HTTP Adapter for urllib3.
>
> Provides a general-case interface for Requests sessions to contact HTTP and HTTPS urls by implementing the Transport Adapter interface. This class will usually be created by the Session class under the covers.
>
> Parameters:
>   * `pool_connections` – The number of urllib3 connection pools to cache.
>   * `pool_maxsize` – The maximum number of connections to save in the pool.
>   * `max_retries(int)` – The maximum number of retries each connection should attempt. Note, this applies only to failed DNS lookups, socket connections and connection timeouts, never to requests where data has made it to the server. By default, Requests does not retry failed connections. If you need granular control over the conditions under which we retry a request, import urllib3’s Retry class and pass that instead.
>   * `pool_block` – Whether the connection pool should block for connections.
>   Usage:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> a = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3)
>>> s.mount('http://', a)
```

If the above documentation confuses you, here's my explanation: what HTTP Adapter does is simply **providing different configurations for different requests according to target url**. Remember the code above?

```
self.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter())
self.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter())
```

It creates two `HTTPAdapter` objects with the default argument `pool_connections=10, pool_maxsize=10, max_retries=0, pool_block=False`, and mount to `https://` and `http://` respectively, which means configuration of the first `HTTPAdapter()` will be used if you try to send a request to `http://xxx`, and the second `HTTPAdapter()` will be used for requests to `https://xxx`. Thought in this case the two configurations are the same, requests to `http` and `https` are still handled separately. We'll see what it means later.

As I said, the main purpose of this article is to explain `pool_connections` and `pool_maxsize`.

First let's look at `pool_connections`. Yesterday I raised a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837026/whats-the-meaning-of-pool-connections-in-requests-adapters-httpadapter) on stackoverflow cause I'm not sure if my understanding is correct, the answer eliminates my uncertainty. HTTP, as we all know, is based on TCP protocol. An HTTP connection is also a TCP connection, which is  identified by a tuple of **five** values:

```
(<protocol>, <src addr>, <src port>, <dest addr>, <dest port>)
```

Say you've established an HTTP/TCP connection with `www.example.com`, assume the server supports `Keep-Alive`, next time you send request to `www.example.com/a` or `www.example.com/b`, you could just use the same connection cause none of the five values change. In fact, [requests' Session automatically does this for you](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive) and will reuse connections as long as it can.

The question is, what determines if you can reuse old connection or not? Yes, `pool_connections`!

> pool_connections – The number of urllib3 connection pools to cache.

I know, I know, I don't want to brought so many terminologies either, this is the last one, I promise. For easy understanding, **one connection pool corresponds to one host**, that's what it is.

Here's an example(unrelated lines are ignored):

```
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1))
s.get('https://www.baidu.com')
s.get('https://www.zhihu.com')
s.get('https://www.baidu.com')

"""output
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.baidu.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.zhihu.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2621
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.baidu.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
"""
```

`HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1)` is mounted to `https://`, which means only one connection pool persists at a time. After calling `s.get('https://www.baidu.com')`, the cached connection pool is `connectionpool('https://www.baidu.com')`. Now `s.get('https://www.zhihu.com')` came, and the session found that it cannot use the previously cached connection because it's not the same host(one connection pool corresponds to one host, remember?). Therefore the session had to create a new connection pool, or connection if you would like. Since `pool_connections=1`, session cannot hold two connection pools at the same time, thus it abandoned the old one which is `connectionpool('https://www.baidu.com')` and kept the new one which is `connectionpool('https://www.zhihu.com')`. Next `get` is the same. This is why we see three `Starting new HTTPS connection` in logging.

What if we set `pool_connections` to 2:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=2))
s.get('https://www.baidu.com')
s.get('https://www.zhihu.com')
s.get('https://www.baidu.com')
"""output
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.baidu.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.zhihu.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2623
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
"""
```

Great, now we only created connections twice and saved one connection establishing time.

Finally, `pool_maxsize`.

First and foremost, you should be caring about `pool_maxsize` only if you use `Session` in a **multithreaded** environment, like making concurrent requests from multiple threads using the **same** `Session`.

Actually, `pool_maxsize` is an argument for initializing urllib3's [`HTTPConnectionPool`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pools.html#module-urllib3.connectionpool), which is exactly the connection pool we mentioned above.
`HTTPConnectionPool` is a container for a collection of connections to a specific host, and `pool_maxsize` is the number of connections to save that can be reused. If you're running your code in one thread, it's neither possible or needed to create multiple connections to the same host, cause requests library is blocking, so that HTTP request are always sent one after another.

Things are different if there are multiple threads.

```
def thread_get(url):
    s.get(url)

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1, pool_maxsize=2))
t1 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com',))
t2 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com/question/36612174',))
t1.start();t2.start()
t1.join();t2.join()
t3 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com/question/39420364',))
t4 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com/question/21362402',))
t3.start();t4.start()
"""output
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.zhihu.com
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (2): www.zhihu.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /question/36612174 HTTP/1.1" 200 21906
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2606
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /question/21362402 HTTP/1.1" 200 57556
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /question/39420364 HTTP/1.1" 200 28739
"""
```

See? It established two connections for the same host `www.zhihu.com`, like I said, this can only happen in a multithreaded environment.
In this case, we create a connectionpool with `pool_maxsize=2`, and there're no more than two connections at the same time, so it's enough.
We can see that requests from `t3` and `t4` did not create new connections, they reused the old ones.

What if there's not enough size?

```
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1, pool_maxsize=1))
t1 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com',))
t2 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com/question/36612174',))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join();t2.join()
t3 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com/question/39420364',))
t4 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com/question/21362402',))
t3.start();t4.start()
t3.join();t4.join()
"""output
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.zhihu.com
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (2): www.zhihu.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /question/36612174 HTTP/1.1" 200 21906
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2606
WARNING:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Connection pool is full, discarding connection: www.zhihu.com
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (3): www.zhihu.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /question/39420364 HTTP/1.1" 200 28739
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /question/21362402 HTTP/1.1" 200 57556
WARNING:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Connection pool is full, discarding connection: www.zhihu.com
"""
```

Now, `pool_maxsize=1`，warning came as expected:

```
Connection pool is full, discarding connection: www.zhihu.com
```

We can also noticed that since only one connection can be saved in this pool, a new connection is created again for `t3` or `t4`. Obviously this is very inefficient. That's why in urllib3's documentation it says:

> If you’re planning on using such a pool in a multithreaded environment, you should set the maxsize of the pool to a higher number, such as the number of threads.

Last but not least, `HTTPAdapter` instances mounted to different prefix are **independent**.

```
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1, pool_maxsize=2))
s.mount('https://baidu.com', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1, pool_maxsize=1))
t1 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com',))
t2 =Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com/question/36612174',))
t1.start();t2.start()
t1.join();t2.join()
t3 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com/question/39420364',))
t4 = Thread(target=thread_get, args=('https://www.zhihu.com/question/21362402',))
t3.start();t4.start()
t3.join();t4.join()
"""output
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.zhihu.com
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (2): www.zhihu.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /question/36612174 HTTP/1.1" 200 21906
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2623
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /question/39420364 HTTP/1.1" 200 28739
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /question/21362402 HTTP/1.1" 200 57669
"""
```

The above code is easy to understand so I don't explain.

I guess that's all. Hope this article help you understand requests better. BTW I created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/laike9m/ead19c65a416c7022c00) which contains all of the testing code used in this article. Just download and play with it :)

### Appendix

1. For https, requests uses urllib3's [HTTPSConnectionPool](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pools.html#urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPSConnectionPool), but it's pretty much the same as HTTPConnectionPool so I don't differeniate them in this article.
2. `Session`'s `mount` method will ensure the longest prefix gets matched first. Its implementation is pretty interesting so I posted it here.

   ```
   def mount(self, prefix, adapter):
       """Registers a connection adapter to a prefix.
       Adapters are sorted in descending order by key length."""
       self.adapters[prefix] = adapter
       keys_to_move = [k for k in self.adapters if len(k) < len(prefix)]
       for key in keys_to_move:
           self.adapters[key] = self.adapters.pop(key)
   ```

   Note that `self.adapters` is an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same session in multiple threads since it's not thread-safe, as outlined by requests' maintainers - https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1871

Comment: Could you please throw some light on what would happen when the connection object is no more usable(being ideal for long time) and how a client should handle it.

Comment: So, if (1) sessions are not thread-safe; and (2) having local sessions sharing a single adapter is not thread safe too... is there any use case for `pool_maxsize` > 1?

Comment: ```
mount(prefix, adapter)

Registers a connection adapter to a prefix.
Adapters are sorted in descending order by key length.
```
please decipher these 2 sentances for me?

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to @laike9m for the existing Q&A and article, but the existing answers fail to mention the subtleties of `pool_maxsize` and its relation to multithreaded code.

#### Summary

- `pool_connections` is number of connections that can be kept alive in the pool at a given time from one (host, port, scheme) endpoint.  If you want to keep around a max of `n` open TCP connections in a pool for reuse with a `Session`, you want `pool_connections=n`.
- `pool_maxsize` is effectively irrelevant for users of `requests` due to the default value for `pool_block` (in `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter`) being `False` rather than `True`

#### Detail

As correctly pointed out here, `pool_connections` is the maximum number of open connections given the adapter's prefix.  It's best illustrated through example:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
>>> 
>>> from urllib3 import add_stderr_logger
>>> 
>>> add_stderr_logger()  # Turn on requests.packages.urllib3 logging
2018-12-21 20:44:03,979 DEBUG Added a stderr logging handler to logger: urllib3
<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>
>>> 
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1))
>>> 
>>> # 4 consecutive requests to (github.com, 443, https)
... # A new HTTPS (TCP) connection will be established only on the first conn.
... s.get('https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py')
2018-12-21 20:44:03,982 DEBUG Starting new HTTPS connection (1): github.com:443
2018-12-21 20:44:04,381 DEBUG https://github.com:443 "GET /requests/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py HTTP/1.1" 200 None
<Response [200]>
>>> s.get('https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/packages.py')
2018-12-21 20:44:04,548 DEBUG https://github.com:443 "GET /requests/requests/blob/master/requests/packages.py HTTP/1.1" 200 None
<Response [200]>
>>> s.get('https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/__init__.py')
2018-12-21 20:44:04,881 DEBUG https://github.com:443 "GET /urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/__init__.py HTTP/1.1" 200 None
<Response [200]>
>>> s.get('https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py')
2018-12-21 20:44:06,533 DEBUG https://github.com:443 "GET /python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py HTTP/1.1" 200 None
<Response [200]>
```

Above, the max number of connections is 1; it is `(github.com, 443, https)`.  If you want to request a resource from a new (host, port, scheme) triple, the `Session` internally will dump the existing connection to make room for a new one:

```
>>> s.get('https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc4045')
2018-12-21 20:46:11,340 DEBUG Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.rfc-editor.org:443
2018-12-21 20:46:12,185 DEBUG https://www.rfc-editor.org:443 "GET /info/rfc4045 HTTP/1.1" 200 6707
<Response [200]>
>>> s.get('https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc4046')
2018-12-21 20:46:12,667 DEBUG https://www.rfc-editor.org:443 "GET /info/rfc4046 HTTP/1.1" 200 6862
<Response [200]>
>>> s.get('https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc4047')
2018-12-21 20:46:13,837 DEBUG https://www.rfc-editor.org:443 "GET /info/rfc4047 HTTP/1.1" 200 6762
<Response [200]>
```

You can up the number to `pool_connections=2`, then cycle between 3 unique host combinations, and you'll see the same thing in play.  (One other thing to note is that the session will retain and send back cookies in this same way.)

Now for `pool_maxsize`, which is passed to `urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager` and ultimately to `urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPSConnectionPool`.  The docstring for maxsize is:

> Number of connections to save that can be reused. More than 1 is
>   useful in multithreaded situations. **If `block` is set to False,
>   more connections will be created but they will not be saved once
>   they've been used.**

Incidentally, `block=False` is the default for `HTTPAdapter`, even though the default is `True` for `HTTPConnectionPool`.  This implies that `pool_maxsize` has little to no effect for `HTTPAdapter`.

Furthermore, `requests.Session()` is *not* thread safe; you shouldn't use the same `session` instance from multiple threads.  (See [here](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1871) and [here](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2766).)  If you really want to, the safer way to go would be to lend each thread its own localized session instance, then use that session to make requests over multiple URLs, via [`threading.local()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#thread-local-data):

```
import threading
import requests

local = threading.local()  # values will be different for separate threads.

vars(local)  # initially empty; a blank class with no attrs.


def get_or_make_session(**adapter_kwargs):
    # `local` will effectively vary based on the thread that is calling it
    print('get_or_make_session() called from id:', threading.get_ident())

    if not hasattr(local, 'session'):
        session = requests.Session()
        adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(**kwargs)
        session.mount('http://', adapter)
        session.mount('https://', adapter)
        local.session = session
    return local.session
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that `pool_connections` is the count of connections corresponding to unique HTTP URLs. Then, `pool_maxsize` is count of TCP ports connection per HTTP URL.