# Too many open files when using requests package python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using the Python requests package to make a large number of requests to an API. At some point my program however crashes due to 'too many open files'. As I explicitely close my session I do not really know how this can be.

I use the following code:

```
import requests
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

s = requests.session()
s.keep_alive = False


def request(i, mapId, minx, maxx, miny, maxy):
    print(i)
    try:
        with requests.Session() as s:
            r = s.post(
                url + "metadata/polygons",
                timeout=10,
                json={
                    "mapId": mapId,
                    "layer": "percelen",
                    "xMin": minx,
                    "xMax": maxx,
                    "yMin": miny,
                    "yMax": maxy,
                },
            )
            out = r.json()
            s.close()

    except:
        print("something went wrong with: " + str(i))


for i in np.aragne(10000):
    time.sleep(1)
    multiprocessing.Process(target=request, args=argsList[i])
```

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated as I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 10):

"Too many open files" is likely a reference to the fact that each `Session` and its single POST request hogs a TCP socket and therefore a file descriptor.

**First solution:**

Use a single `Session` instance with [a customized `HTTPAdapter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53890776/7954504) and pass a beefed up argument to its `pool_connections` parameter.

Side note 1: you don't need to call `s.close()`.  That's already called when the context manager calls `.__exit__()`.

Side note 2: consider using `threading` or `asyncio`/`aiohttp`.  Multiprocessing is not ideal for an IO-bound task like this.

**Second solution:**

Increase the number of open files permitted.  On Linux, you'll need to do something like:

```
sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf
# Add these lines
root    soft    nofile  100000
root    hard    nofile  100000
ubuntu    soft    nofile  100000
ubuntu    hard    nofile  100000

sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
# Add this line
fs.file-max = 2097152

sudo sysctl -p

sudo vim /etc/pam.d/commmon_session
# Add this line
session required pam_limits.so

sudo reboot
```

I think this second solution could be characterized as "fixing the symptom rather than the problem," but try it if you must and are feeling bold.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem as the OP. Can you please explain what you mean by passing "a beefed up argument to its pool_connections parameter"? An example would be greatly appreciated!