# Azure functions python - how to prevent SNAT port exhaustion?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

So I have an Azure functions app written in python and quite often the code throws an error like this.

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.***.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /x/y/z (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7faba31d0438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

This happens in a few diffrent functions that make https connections.

I contacted support and they told me that this was caused by SNAT port exhaustion and adviced me to: "Modify the application to reuse connections instead of creating a connection per request, use connection pooling, use service endpoints if the you are connecting to resources in Azure." They sent me this link https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/ and also this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections

Problem is I am unsure about how to practically reuse and or pool connections in python and I am unsure what the primary cause of exhaustion is, as this data is not publicly available.

So I am looking for help with applying their advice to all our http(s) and database connections.

I made the assumption that pymongo and pyodbc (the database clients we use) would handle pooling an reuse despite me creating a new client each time a function runs. Is this incorrect and if so, how do I reuse these database clients in python to prevent this?

The problem has so far only been caused when using `requests` (or the zeep SOAP library that internally defaults to using `requests`) to hit a https endpoint. Is there any way I could improve how I use `requests`. Like reusing sessions or closing connections explicitly. I am aware that requests creates a session in the background when calling `requests.get`. But my knowledge about the library is insufficient to figure out if this is the problem and how I could solve it. I am thinking I might be able to create and reuse a single session instance for each specific http(s) call in each function, but I am unsure if this is correct and also I have no idea on how to actually do it.

In a few places I also use aiohttp and if possible would like to achive the same thing there.

I haven't looked into service endpoints yet but I am about to.

So in short. What can I in pratice do to ensure reusage/pooling with requests, pyodbc, pymongo and aiohttp?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34893364/4148708). TL;DR - use an HTTPAdapter with a connection pool, beware sessions are not thread safe.

Comment: Sorry I might be missunderstanding you. If the default pool size is 10. Then I am by default using a HTTPAdapter with a connection pool? Do you mean it would make a difference if I changed the size?

Comment: @evilSnobu or do you mean that I should use a global HTTPAdpter for all my Sessions? That would give them access to the same connections meaning I could reuse them when creating a new session.