# eventlet.monkey_patch cause: maximum recursion depth exceeded in ssl.py

Tags: python, connection-pooling, monkeypatching

In a python 3.10.9 docker container, the app depends on a critical package what uses `eventlet.monkey_patch(socket=True)`. Unfortunatelly this cause `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` when `requests.Session().get()` called.

Here is the code snippet

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=2))
s.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837026/whats-the-meaning-of-pool-connections-in-requests-adapters-httpadapter')
# <Response [200]>

import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch(socket=True)

s.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837026/whats-the-meaning-of-pool-connections-in-requests-adapters-httpadapter')
# <Response [200]>

s.get('https://www.google.com/')
# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

s.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837026/whats-the-meaning-of-pool-connections-in-requests-adapters-httpadapter')
# <Response [200]>
```

Is there any possible way to make `urllib3.HTTPSConnection.connect(self)` be coperative with a patched `socket`.

So far the only trick I found is to warm up the connection pools before monkey_patch applied.

I must deal with`eventlet.monkey_patch(socket=True)`. It is not an option to replace it with `gevent` or rewrite.